# auto database creation in hibernate with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

this is my code, where i done mistake. while running Test.java am getting error like "The requested resource is not available". i kept all this files in same package

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
 <property name="connection.pool_size"> 1</property> 

   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>


   <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
   <mapping resource="student.hbm.xml"/>

   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    }

}
```

**student.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.javathub.Student" table="stu_details">
<id name="id">
<generator class="assigned"></generator>
</id>
<property name="name"></property>
<property name="branch"></property>
<property name="fee"></property>
</class>


</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String branch;
    private double fee;
    public Student(){

    }
    public Student(int id, String name, String branch, double fee) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.branch = branch;
        this.fee = fee;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }
    public void setBranch(String branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }
    public double getFee() {
        return fee;
    }
    public void setFee(double fee) {
        this.fee = fee;
    }

}
```

please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Update your hibernate mapping class with the package of Student.java like so <mapping package="package.of.Student.class"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep the student.hbm.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml in src folder not in package and run again.

Comment: thank you, got the solution, but in dynamic web project it is not creating. if we give input from jsp then it is creating and store the data into database. how can i create auto table without giving input from jsp?  i should write anything in web.xml? i write code same as above